# Sklearn logistic regression, plotting probability curve graph

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a logistic regression similar to the ISLR's example, but using python instead

```
data=pd.read_csv("data/Default.csv")

#first we'll have to convert the strings "No" and "Yes" to numeric values
data.loc[data["default"]=="No", "default"]=0
data.loc[data["default"]=="Yes", "default"]=1
X = data["balance"].values.reshape(-1,1)
Y = data["default"].values.reshape(-1,1)

LogR = LogisticRegression()
LogR.fit(X,np.ravel(Y.astype(int)))

#matplotlib scatter funcion w/ logistic regression
plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.xlabel("Credit Balance")
plt.ylabel("Probability of Default")
```

But I keep getting the graph on the left, when I want the one on the right:

[image]

Edit: `plt.scatter(x,LogR.predict(x))` was my second, and also wrong guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you use `predict(X)` which gives out the prediction of the class.
replace `predict(X)` with `predict_proba(X)[:,1]` which would gives out the probability of which the data belong to class 1.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [seaborn regplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) with the following syntax

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.regplot(x='balance', y='default', data=data, logistic=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x_range = 80
Xs = [i for i in range(x_range)]
Ys = [model.predict_proba([[value]])[0][1] for value in range(x_range)]

plt.scatter(df['X'], df['y'])
plt.plot(Xs, Ys, color='red')
```

Comment: Please add some descriptions of your code to give context to your answer

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28052645)